# WPF DataGrid control x:Name isn't found. "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Tags: wpf, datagrid, wpf-controls

This WPF MVVM project uses uses material UI, Ninject, Prism, ICommand. I bind `Home.xaml` with a `GridViewModel.cs`:

```
Bind<Home>().ToSelf().InTransientScope().WithPropertyValue("DataContext", x => x.Kernel.Get<GridViewModel>());
```

In GridViewModel I wrote `private readonly System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid dataGrid1;` as a reference to the x:Name of the DataGrid in the Home.xaml.  In the `Home.xaml` there's `<DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid1"....>`. Everything works fine until I come across calling the dataGrid1 from ViewModel. It says `"Object reference not set to an instance of an object"` if I call `dataGrid1.Columns[1].Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;`

What seems to be the issue?

GridViewModel.cs

```
public class GridViewModel : BasePageViewMode
{
   private readonly System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid dataGrid1;

   GridViewModel()
   {
      dataGrid1.Columns[1].Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
   }
}
```

Home.xaml

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid1">
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: `<DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid1"....>` generates a private field `dataGrid1` in Home.xaml.cs. You can not access it by a *different* field that you added to some other class. Besides that, a view model must not access a view element. The view model does not know the view.

Comment: I'm relatively new to this so how can I manipulate the DataGrid? I want to hide a certain column so as not to be displayed.

Comment: By setting the Visibility property in XAML. Why is the column there at all when it is never visible?

Comment: Column is being populated automatically with the properties of the class Products.
`<DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid1" ItemsSource="{Binding Products}" ...>`

Comment: You should take a look at the DataGrid documentation. There you'll find the AutoGenerateColumns property.

Comment: Cool! Thanks man.

Answer (score 0):

Initially, I was able to fix this by creating a class that maps from the original class then change the Binding to the new object. Although it was fixed, I had another issue, i.e I want my columns not to be automatically generated because column names are not good to read as they have underscore and all capital letters. So I bring back the original class, then in the xaml I define the datagrid columns with their column binding.

Sorry I relatively new to WPF thingy.